# Lua 'require' but files are only in memory

Tags: lua

Setting: I'm using Lua from a C/C++ environment.

I have several lua files on disk. Those are read into memory and some more memory-only lua files become available during runtime. Think e.g. of an editor, with additional unsaved lua files.

So, I have a `list<identifier, lua_file_content>` in memory. Some of these files have `require` statements in them. When I try to load all these files to a lua instance (currently via `lua_dostring`) I get `attempt to call global require (a nil value)`.

Is there a possibility to provide a `require` function, which replaces the old one and just uses the provided in memory files (those files are on the C side)?

Is there another way of allowing `require` in these files without having the required files on disk?

An example would be to load the lua stdlib from memory only without altering it. (This is actually my test case.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of replacing `require`, why not add a function to `package.loaders`? The code is nearly the same.

```c
int my_loader(lua_State* state) {
    // get the module name
    const char* name = lua_tostring(state);
    // find if you have such module loaded
    if (mymodules.find(name) != mymodules.end())
    {
        luaL_loadbuffer(state, buffer, size, name);
        // the chunk is now at the top of the stack
        return 1;
    }

    // didn't find anything
    return 0;
}

// When you load the lua state, insert this into package.loaders
```

http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.loaders

Comment: Thank you very much, works also very well. Since it seems to be the better solution, because it handles the package.loaded implicitely, I changed the accepted solution to this.

Answer (score 5):

A pretty straightforward C++ function that would mimic `require` could be: (pseudocode)

```c
int my_require(lua_State* state) {
    // get the module name
    const char* name = lua_tostring(state);
    // find if you have such module loaded
    if (mymodules.find(name) != mymodules.end())
        luaL_loadbuffer(state, buffer, size, name);
    // the chunk is now at the top of the stack
    lua_call(state)
    return 1;
}
```

Expose this function to Lua as `require` and you're good to go.

I'd also like to add that to completely mimic `require`'s behaviour, you'd probably need to take care of `package.loaded`, to avoid the code to be loaded twice.

Comment: Sorry, I'm no Lua expert. I would guess I provide this function with the name `require` to the lua instance before loading the files from memory?

Comment: @MikeM please see my edit about `package.path`, I feel like this might be an important thing I forgot to mention.

Comment: Doesn't `lua_call` need 3 arguments?

Comment: I tried to have my own `package.loaded`, given true to require when a package was loaded the second time. But this doesn't work. It seems to me, I really have to put the file on the stack for each require. However, since I have the files in memory I don't have to load them again. @BartekBanachewicz does that seem reasonable to you? Btw `lua_call`really needs 3 arguments, but I replaced loadbuffer and call with `luaL_dostring`, which works fine.

Comment: "Reasonable" depends on your use case here. Lua's default behaviour (when not embedded) is to only load each file once and fill up the `package.path`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no package.loaders in lua 5.2
It called package.searchers now.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <lua.hpp>

std::string    module_script;


int MyLoader(lua_State *L)
{
    const char *name = luaL_checkstring(L, 1);  // Module name

//  std::string    result = SearchScript(name); // Search your database.
    std::string    result = module_script;      // Just for demo.

    if( luaL_loadbuffer(L, result.c_str(), result.size(), name) )
    {
        printf("%s", lua_tostring(L, -1));
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }

    return 1;
}

void SetLoader(lua_State* L)
{
    lua_register(L, "my_loader", MyLoader);

    std::string     str;

//  str += "table.insert(package.loaders,   2, my_loader) \n";   // Older than lua v5.2
    str += "table.insert(package.searchers, 2, my_loader) \n";

    luaL_dostring(L, str.c_str());
}

void SetModule()
{
    std::string     str;

    str += "print([[It is add.lua]]) \n";
    str += "return { func = function() print([[message from add.lua]]) end } \n";

    module_script=str;
}

void LoadMainScript(lua_State* L)
{
    std::string     str;

    str += "dev = require [[add]] \n";
    str += "print([[It is main.lua]]) \n";
    str += "dev.func() \n";

    if ( luaL_loadbuffer(L, str.c_str(), str.size(), "main") )
    {
        printf("%s", lua_tostring(L, -1));
        lua_pop(L, 1);
        return;
    }
}

int main()
{
    lua_State*  L = luaL_newstate();

    luaL_openlibs(L);

    SetModule(L);       // Write down module in memory. Lua not load it yet.
    SetLoader(L);
    LoadMainScript(L);

    lua_pcall(L,0,0,0);
    lua_close(L);

    return 0;
}
```