# How can I bundle Lua scripts to single file

Tags: build, lua, bundle

I need to create single lua file based on source ones.

i.e as input I have some project where there are several modules which use **require** statements. As output I need single lua file (still source file but bundled) and after that I suppose it will not have any **require** statements.

How can I do it ?

Comment: you copy the contents of all script into one? I presume you require script files

Comment: you can not "bundle" all contents if you are using modules that are not pure lua. Why are you looking to "bundle" the source into a single file?

Comment: @Nifim the place where I need bundle consumes only single file. I suppose it should have some build tool for bundling.

Comment: @Piglet I can not just copy the contents as some modules could be required several times => I need to create dependency graph and etc... I expected that there are build tools for such purposes.

Comment: you cannot require things several times. they will be executed only once. that's the whole purpose of require. if you want to have all code in one file you have full control over the whole code. if you have only modules scripted in Lua it is pretty obvious what to do if you know what require does.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18965489/lua-require-but-files-are-only-in-memory?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through all files and you can replace the require function to something like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------ HEADER
local files = {}
local globalRequire = require -- Store default require reference
local require = function(path) -- Will return saved file or attempt default lua require
    return files[path] or globalRequire(path)
end
------------------------------------------------------ START FILES
files["file1"] = function(...)
------------------------------------------------------ FILE #1 CONTENTS
local hola = require("file2")
local file1 = {}

return file1
------------------------------------------------------ FILES CONTINUE
end
files["file2"] = function(...)
------------------------------------------------------ FILE #2 CONTENTS
local file2 = {}

return file2
------------------------------------------------------ FOOTER
end
------------------------------------------------------ EOF
```

Notice how in most lua files you return something at the EOF? This is because files in lua are technically functions, so you can do it this way. It is important to also supply the (...) three dot parameter as it also gets passed in to modules, although it usually only contains the module name.

Anyway, you can build a script that puts this together and it should work, or with a few tweaks.